# Error with Perl interpreter and glossaries package on Windows

Tags: errors, glossaries, perl

I'm a relatively new user of Latex. I'm using TeXStudio on a Windows 8.1 system writing a long document (document class book). I'm trying to make glossaries package work properly and after ~2-3h of googling it kinda work. The same TeXStudio on a MacBook, with exact same *.tex files work flawlessly.

On windows, when I compile the glossary (F9), i get the following:

```
Unescaped left brace in regex is illegal here in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\\@input{ <-- HERE (.+)\.aux/ at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\glossaries\makeglossaries line 634.
```

I'm not familiar with Perl syntax, but the 634 line is the following:

```
634 if (m/\\\@input{(.+)\.aux/})
635    {
636       &scan_aux($1);
 .
 .      # v2.04 added
 .      # (Fix provided by Daniel Grund) 
 .      next;
641    }
```

Compiling on the Mac is working properly.

I want to make it work on the windows system, as it's the professional computer that I use more often (I don't carry my Mac at work or my Win at home).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
...
\usepackage[acronym, toc]{glossaries}
\input{./Tex_files/glossary.tex}
\makeglossaries
```

The glossary.tex is the following:

```
\newacronym{EBL}{EBL}{Electron Blocking Layer}
\newacronym{TFB}{TFB}{name)}
```

And i cite in the text as follows in two occasions, in chapters 1 and 2.

```
\acrfull{EBL}
\acrfull{TFB}
```

The main.tex file i use after the \begin{document} is as follows:

```
\begin{document}
....
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, title= List of Abbreviations]
\mainmatter
\include{./TeX_files/chapter01} % Chapter 1
\include{./TeX_files/chapter02} % Chapter 2
```

I installed the Strawberry Perl version 5.26 64bit from perl.org as before installing it I got the message : "Perl interpreter not found".

My google searching didn't show any relative answers and therefore the post.. Sorry if it's a duplicate!

Many thanks in advance...

Alex

PS. Edited the document to add preamble and the rest of the code.

Comment: Showing a complete, minimal example that demonstrates the error *is* necessary. How else can we test if we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited the text to add the parts missing.

Comment: This is not minimal.

Comment: Being a beginner user, I am not 100% sure, but my intuition says that it's not related to the preamble or the documents, as on a different OS it's working. Therefore I believe that it's more related to Perl or Windows... To avoid any further questions, i prefer being more detailed to help any of the readers... Sorry if it's too long.. I'll try to reduce it a bit.

Comment: Your version of `glossaries` needs updating.

Comment: @AlexandrosRapidis Your problem is probably resolved by Nicola's remark. But a remark regarding the example: In most cases it should be so that others can copy&paste it and try out if they can reproduce the problem and then perhaps debug it. This is easiest if examples are short and self-contained. `\input`, `\include` and snippets collections makes it more difficult to test the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is your Perl version on Windows. As you can see at the [Perl doc site](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl-5.26.0/pod/perldelta.pod#Unescaped_literal_"%7B"_characters_in_regular_expression_patterns_are_no_longer_permissible), one of the changes introduced in Perl 5.26 was forbidding of using unescaped braces `{` and `}` in regular expressions.

<s>This means that line 634 in the `makeglossaries` script is now considered a bug and has to be reported to the `glossaries` package authors and fixed.</s> This bug is already fixed, as Nicola Talbot said.

So if you can, you should upgrade your `glossaries` package.

If you can't do that you can escape the braces yourself (by prepending backslash to them) in this and other places

```
634 if (m/\\\@input\{(.+)\.aux/\})
635    {
636       &scan_aux($1);
 .
 .      # v2.04 added
 .      # (Fix provided by Daniel Grund) 
 .      next;
641    }
```

or downgrade your Perl distribution to 5.24.

Comment: The problem was fixed back in v2.17. (The current version of `makeglossaries` is v2.21.) So the simplest solution is to upgrade to the latest version of `glossaries`.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: Thank you for pointing to that. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot and Sergei Many thanks for your answer guys. Much appreciated. Uninstalling and reinstalling Miktex 2.9 fixed the solution. Now I do get a warning of "XX.glo" is empty, but the compiling is going through!

Comment: @AlexandrosRapidis The empty `.glo` warning means you haven't used any entries in the `main` glossary. I'm guessing you're just using the `acronym` glossary. In which case use the package option `nomain` to indicate that you don't need the main (`.glo`) glossary and the warning should go away.